# Hibernate session.save with Update query

Tags: hibernate

i have a `session.save()` which performs the insert operations. and there is a condition that gives the number of rows updated `if !=null`. now i wanted to know how can i know whether the `session.save()` is successful or not?

thanks in advance

Comment: If there is any exception, then session.save() will throw it. If not not then it guarantees that the object is saved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using transactions and the save() didn't throw any exception, it [returns the generated identifier](http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/Session.html) indicating a success.